# How to disable rotation on horizontal axis in the VRPanoramaView in android

Tags: android, google-vr, 360-panorama-viewer

I started using Google VR library in my application to view 360 images. What I want to do is to disable the rotation on the horizontal axis, I want to make sort of only 180 image (cylindric image). Is there a way to make it with Google VR library or it would be appreciated if there's another library that meets my need.

I also tried PanoramaGL but I encountered many problems : Accelerometer rotation not working, rendering is very slow and when I disable the X axis it stills work.